# is there a way to connect SAMBA and miniDLNA

Tags: debian, samba

I am quite new to both, SAMBA and DLNA, so I don't know if my attempt makes sense at all.

But what I try to achieve is the following:
I have a client, that supports DLNA and a server that is a computer running Debian (Wheezy). I would like to access files released on the server (using SAMBA) with the client.

This way I could control which files in my home directory should be shared via DLNA and which should stay private.

Therefore I thought of a solution where I put something like

```
media_dir= # some place whith all samba shares
```

in `/etc/minidlna.conf`

I think in this tutorial (http://zeldor.biz/2012/01/dlna-minidlna-on-debian/) the author tries to do something similar.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

I am too lazy to read the minidlna documentation, but with workaround should work. Use mount cifs to mount samba share to folder, and then add this folder to minidlna library.